# ASP.NET 7 restarts docker container with error traps: .NET ThreadPool general protection fault error:0 in libc-2.31.so

Tags: linux, docker, .net-core, threadpool, ubuntu-20.04

I have ASP.NET 7 application running in a docker container on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.
It works fine for a year, but last two weeks it's start to restart the docker container with no reason.
The error from syslog gives this:

> traps: .NET ThreadPool[241403] general protection fault
> ip:7f512ca26602 sp:7f50aca21c10 error:0 in
> libc-2.31.so[7f512ca26000+159000]

But there is no any work items at that time in a thread pool.

Can anyone help with direction or reason why this error happen?
Which approach I can use to diagnose and get root cause of the problem or at least get the understanding of the problem?

Comment: What kind of machine do you use to build the container, and what kind of machine do you run the container on ? Errors around libc usually indicate an architecture incompatibility between the container and the host machine. Also, what's the exact base image you're using ?

Comment: @ABWassim I use Windows 11 Pro x64 and docker desktop to build the container. The container host is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. You suspect problem related because of different build and host machine?

Comment: My initial guess was that you were building the image on a machine with an ARM processor but running the image on a machine with an AMD processor (or vice-versa). Does it work properly when you run a container image older than 2 weeks ? They could also have pushed something bugged over the same tag you use for you base image

Comment: @ABWassim can't say for sure, before I did not discover such behaviour in production, but users start to report that application become unresponsive for couple of minutes and I start investigation. That lead me to issue with container restarts and after that I discover error in the description. I just want to understand is it problem with memory, access or file system. Also these restarts are floating so can't reproduce it to diagnise with strace

Comment: What's the exact base image you use for that container (i.e the ```FROM``` image) ? Can you try (re)installing ```build-essential``` in your image ? ```apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential```

Comment: @ABWassim I found the reason, you can check it here https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/95694

Comment: Nice, feel free to answer you post and mark it as answer to let other people know if they come across the same issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason of such behaviour. It happens because unhandled exceptions from a thread or the thread pool will exit the entire process. From miscrosoft documentation:

> The common language runtime allows most unhandled exceptions in
> threads to proceed naturally. In most cases, this means that the
> unhandled exception causes the application to terminate. However, the
> common language runtime provides a backstop for certain unhandled
> exceptions that are used for controlling program flow:
>
> A ThreadAbortException is thrown in a thread because Abort was called.
> This only applies to .NET Framework apps.
>
> An AppDomainUnloadedException is thrown in a thread because the
> application domain in which the thread is executing is being unloaded.
>
> The common language runtime or a host process terminates the thread by
> throwing an internal exception.
>
> If any of these exceptions are unhandled in threads created by the
> common language runtime, the exception terminates the thread, but the
> common language runtime does not allow the exception to proceed
> further.
>
> If these exceptions are unhandled in the main thread, or in threads
> that entered the runtime from unmanaged code, they proceed normally,
> resulting in termination of the application.